# Android : row spanning for images

Tags: android, image

In my application i want to display 5 images in 2 columns and 3 rows
Image1 actually spans colum 1 of row 1 and row 2 . rest all images occupy just one cell

SO the layout is

```
             image1    image2

                       image3

             image4    image5
```

because of this row spanning , i couldnt use grid view or tabular layout
I tried to define within linear and relative layout.
But i am not able to get the inages aligned properly.

Please suggest help me out here. I want t define in such a way that the images will be resized accrording to screen size

Please see the xml i have defined. I have added several options to make it look the way i wanted .

```
<LinerLayout .. >
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/img1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_below="@+id/text1view" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1" android:src="@drawable/imqge2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1view" android:onClick="" 
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1" android:src="@drawable/image3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image2" android:onClick=""
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  />      
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image4" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image1" android:onClick="" />
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image5" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image3" android:onClick="" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image4"  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Latest edited code :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="2">
         <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:src="@drawable/rotating_img1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1view" android:scaleType="fitXY" 
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/aboutklink"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/about" android:onClick="" android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" 
         >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/products"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/products" android:onClick="" android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/productspackages"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/special_prod" android:layout_below="@+id/products"
                android:onClick="" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/events" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip" android:src="@drawable/events"
                android:onClick="" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can easily do it with Linear and Relative Layout. And even if you have tried then post the xml layout code here.

Comment: i have added the xml part. please see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="3"> 


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
     <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView> 
       </LinearLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
     <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
         android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView> 
       </LinearLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
     <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1" android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp" android:scaleType="fitXY" 
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView> 
       </LinearLayout> 
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Now images are correctly fiiling parent horizontally. but i still have the issue with image 1. I want image 1 to occupy col1 of row1 and row 2 ( if you think it as a table with 3 rows and 2 cols each ). Now image1 is occupying only row 1 col1 and row2 col2 is empty as i didnt mention any source for that. Please see my xml below

Comment: i cant add code here due to size. i just have the same code as your , changing the android:id android:src

Comment: this can be some what complex, but let me try..if i could will update my ans.

Comment: @preetha Suggestion to you that you start making xml with fix sizes and use RELATIVE LAYOUT and make xml for 3 different sizes ..that will be much easier than this..

Comment: you mean to specify height and width in dip ?

Comment: yes just try that untill dont get solution in this way..also you can use relative layout to define toLeft Right above below..

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I had good learning about the power of android:weight parameter. thank you

Comment: While trying to implement , i got this idea. Here using linear/ relative layout 3 rows are defined each with 2 columns. Similarly instead of this if 2 columns , one with 2 images and second with 3 images if defined, it should solve the problem. I tried modifying your code but not fully correct. Can you please have a look at the code i have added now to my question. If you can find my mistake it would be really great

Comment: i could correct it, the corrected code given in my first question. Please have a look . i had to modify the weight sums . can you pls explain how 0dip works

Comment: when you use 0dp that gets widht or height fit to the weight area..need to look at you xml..and will tell u