# Android : image size defining

Tags: android, image

I want to place my images within a Liner layout / Relative Layout

I want to keep two images in a row .
How do i define the width of these images so that , both together fills the parent horizontally.

I can use layout_margin for the required gap between the images. But i am not able to define the width so that it fills the parent.

Do i have to do trial with different dip values

Comment: use android:layout_weight , see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-is-androidlayout-weight-meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way in your xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2">
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="0dp" android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you.can you please look in to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834737/android-row-spanning-for-images/7834816#7834816 and correct my xml .

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:layout_weight="1"  for parent
and android:layout_weight="0.5" for childs
```

Comment: +1 nice answer ..would be more nice to put the way how to give image height width..

Answer (score 0):

set `LinearLayout`'s orientation to Horizontal

Put two `ImageViews` with property

```
android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:layout_weight = "1"
```

Comment: Actually this question was my partial requirement. The actual question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834737/android-row-spanning-for-images/7834816#7834816

Comment: Since i didnt get answer i was trying to attack problem by problem. It would be great if you have any solutions for my problem. I trie by assigning weight but its not working